# How to download image from aws s3 into imageview?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-imageview, android-glide

so I want to be able to grab my images from my s3 bucket and (using glide or picasso) load that image into an imageview. (I don't want to download that image into my phone).

currently i have this:

```
 downloadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cognito_s3DownloadButton);
        downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + "fromAWS");
                observer = transferUtility.download("zivit-card-images","image1", file);
                Glide.with(getBaseContext()).load("image in byes? or url?").centerCrop().into(myImageView);
            }
        });
```

Again, how do i retrieve the image from s3 and insert it into an imageview?

Comment: you are passing a file reference to the `transferUtility.download()`, thats the file to which transfer utility will download the s3 object to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Glide or Picasso, you need not worry about the location where the `image` will be saved. Picasso or Glide takes care of the `Caching` so that you don't have to.

Now, all you need to set an Image to an ImageView using Glide or Picasso is an image `URL`. I think you want to use an image from your S3 bucket, then you need to have an image from your S3 bucket, something like this:

```
https://a2.muscache.com/im/pictures/9c66dcc5-6d39-43b3-82ec-72e9d119f873.jpg
```

then all you need to do with your code is:

```
downloadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cognito_s3DownloadButton);
   downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Glide.with(getBaseContext())
                 .load("https://a2.muscache.com/im/pictures/9c66dcc5-6d39-43b3-82ec-72e9d119f873.jpg")
                 .centerCrop()
                 .into(myImageView);
       }
});
```

Comment: from the TransferObserver object, how do i grab the image's url? In general, what is the way to get an image s3 url? Would you be able to include that in your code?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with S3, you need to handle the S3 stuff by yourself, however, the S3 image URL should be just like any other image URL, so the following code will work for S3 images too.

Comment: yeah thats fine, thats fine. Appreciate the response

Comment: @Dr.Android did you have to create a signed url or no?

Answer (score 4):

```
public String downloadimage()

    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, +1);
        Date oneHourLater = cal.getTime();
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        URL url = s3.generatePresignedUrl(
                "testproject12345",
                "first.jpg",
                oneHourLater
        );
        Log.e("url was", url.toString());
        String urlstring = url.toString();
        return urlstring;
    }

catch that function in your activity


download = (Button)findViewById(R.id.download);
        final ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

 download1 = new Uploader(getmain().getCredentialsProvider(),getApplicationContext());


                String url = download1.downloadimage();
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(url)
                        .into(imageview);


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

As showed @Prog, you have to use

```
amazonS3Client!!.generatePresignedUrl({your_bucket_name}, {your_key_image_file}, {expiration_date_of_url})
```

to generate an url than you can use with Picasso.

But be careful, you have to generate the url only the first time. Store it and re-use it while it is not expired.
Each time you use aws method to generate an url, the response is a new url. So you will not get your image in cache because his associated url is another one. You will proceed the http call again.

Sorry for my english,
Hope is help,
Thomas